# checking for a node in XML (minidom) and insering if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, xml

I have pretty simple XML. I need to check if 2 nodes exist: preferences and item, inside it. There can be multiple items.

```
<settings>
    <preferences>
        <item>sometext</item>
    </preferences>
</settings>
```

Now, if  exists, I need to check nodeValue. If needed nodeValue is not there, I need to add it.

So far I am reading the file and looking for  node but I don't know how to add it if it's not there (and save the file):

```
def readSettings(xmlFile):
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(xmlFile)
    cNodes = xmldoc.childNodes
    boo = 0

    try:
        nList = cNodes[0].getElementsByTagName("preferences")
        eList = nList[0].getElementsByTagName("item")

        for a in eList:
            tempstr=a.childNodes[0].nodeValue
            if tempstr == 'yes':
                ### it is there, we don't need to do anything
                boo = 1
                break
    except:
        boo = 0

    return( boo )
```

So, if boo is 0, that means node `<item>` with Nodevalue "yes" `(<item>yes</item>`) was not found.

How do I write it to this existing XML?

Comment: Minidom? Ewwww. Any particular reason you chose one of the oldest and hardest-to-use XML APIs bundled with Python?

Comment: I must - I'm using python 2.7 for Kodi and minidom is included with Kodi... also It's only a small part of a code, I'm not doing anything much with XML just need to check if node exists if not add it....

Comment: Python 2.7 includes much more than just minidom -- it also has ElementTree.

Comment: Hmm, true. I thought Minidom was simplest and smallest and most important, enough for what I need :) But if it's much easier to do it in ElementTree, hell, why not :)